# Android application not starting from shortcut

Tags: android, operating-system, shortcut, environment

My application not starting from shortcut on device screen, but start from application list.
This behaviour is reported for android 4.x
This problem appears after installing application update.
Shortcut is created for previous one. I'm not sure who created it - OS or user.

**Update:**
Can I add/remove shortcut from home screen during install/uninstall?

Comment: I noticed this behavior when shortcut was created programmatically and application was then reinstalled. Is it this case?

Comment: This problem appears after installing next version. Shortcut is created for previous one. I'm not sure who created it - OS or user.

Comment: Does rebooting the device help?

Comment: Follow messages in LogCat!

Comment: Is this based on a field report, or is it a problem that you are able to recreate ? Is the problem "fixed" when you uninstall and reinstall the app ?

Comment: I'll try again - are you able to recreate the problem ?

Comment: One more question - how many users have been affected by this ?

Comment: About 100 from 100k. But problem will be the same in other applications when publish them.

Comment: Is this a reported bug in google.code?

Comment: It wasn't reported in the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the application update changed the launcher activity name, then the shortcut can no longer find the application. See [Things That Cannot Be Done](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html) for an explanation: basically your manifest xml is public API that you should only change very carefully.

If this is the case in your application, there is a way to [disable old launcher activity](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher) (which should remove all icons and shortcuts pointing to it) but I'm not sure if the disadvantages mentioned on the page still apply.

Comment: The only difference is version - this is alloved and doesn't produce such problems.

Answer (score 2):

As you are well aware (but someone else who reads this may not be) this could be a problem with your manifest or launcher icon such that Android did not or  could not install the new icon on the device. Android might leave the old icon there because it could not install the new one (or you did not tell it to install the new one).

**If this were the case, the problem would probably affect many users and you would be able to recreate
and solve the problem yourself. Moreover you have said that there has been no change to the manifest/icon.**

ONE Since you opened this a year ago and have provided very little information, I'm guessing that this affects only a very small number of devices and/or users.

TWO I don't think you have been able to narrow it down to specific devices or users or I think you would have told us.

THREE So we are probably talking about a problem that affects a small number of users on different devices.

**Update: you have now replied to one of my questions and said 100 out of 100,000.**

If you phoned up Google and told them that your app had only successfully installed on 99.9% of devices, I'm sure they would be delighted (they might not say that to you).

**Do you have any information on what percentage of those 0.1% were able to subsequently uninstall / install ?**

Judging by the popularity of products such as Titanium Backup, the number of rooted Android devices is probably significantly more than 0.1%.

PackageManager, packages.xml and packages.list are well known targets for people who root their phones. PackageManager is just a jar, and there is an opensource version available. A permissions problem or an invalid entry in one of these files could easily account for the problem you see.

Even if this problem is nothing to do with rooting, earlier versions of Android Market / Package Manager running on old devices with fewer resources were far less reliable than (for example) my (non rooted) Nexus 7 running Jelly Bean. I have been unable to recreate your problem on my Nexus 7. There again, I wouldn't expect to - based on what you have told us, it is highly unlikely that this is "your problem".

> Update: Can I add/remove shortcut from home screen during
>   install/uninstall?

Well, it's not ideal, but how about this approach ?

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/removing-app-icon-launcher

Comment: As a user, I personally had this issue a couple of times on my non-rooted Nexus 7 for some application updates. That being said, I agree with Sheldon, this is a non-issue for me and it's an issue I would blame on Google Play (not on the particular application that was getting updated). For a while may be a year or two years ago on my other devices, the Google Market would randomly fail to initially install an application on its first try. Now this problem has pretty much completely disappeared since that time, but I still wouldn't expect Google Play to be 100% perfect at everything it does.

Answer (score 1):

May be for both applications package names are different plz check package names

Comment: The only difference is version.